# Работа с многомерными массивами

Tags: массивы, php

Всем привет.

Что-то никак не могу понять как обработать массив.

Нужно обработать массив так, чтобы из

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 244
                    [file_id] => 2
                    [category_id] => 2
                    [parent_id] => 0
                    [name] => Детский транспорт
                    [c_id] => 19
                    [child] => Array
                        (
                        )
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 244
                    [file_id] => 2
                    [category_id] => 2
                    [parent_id] => 0
                    [name] => Детский транспорт
                    [c_id] => 19
                    [child] => Array
                        (
                            [9] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 258
                                    [file_id] => 2
                                    [category_id] => 9
                                    [parent_id] => 2
                                    [name] => Коляски
                                    [c_id] => 4
                                    [child] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [5] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [file_id] => 2
                    [category_id] => 5
                    [parent_id] => 0
                    [name] => Каталог детских игрушек
                    [c_id] => 0
                    [child] => Array
                        (
                            [6] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 8
                                    [file_id] => 2
                                    [category_id] => 6
                                    [parent_id] => 5
                                    [name] => Развивающие игрушки
                                    [c_id] => 0
                                    [child] => Array
                                        (
                                            [28] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [id] => 20
                                                    [file_id] => 2
                                                    [category_id] => 28
                                                    [parent_id] => 6
                                                    [name] => Развивающие пособия
                                                    [c_id] => 0
                                                    [child] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [26] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                    [id] => 21
                                                                    [file_id] => 2
                                                                    [category_id] => 26
                                                                    [parent_id] => 28
                                                                    [name] => Учим буквы, цифры и слова
                                                                    [c_id] => 19
                                                                    [child] => Array
                                                                        (
                                                                        )

                                                                )

                                                        )

                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 244
                    [file_id] => 2
                    [category_id] => 2
                    [parent_id] => 0
                    [name] => Детский транспорт
                    [c_id] => 19
                    [child] => Array
                        (
                            [9] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 258
                                    [file_id] => 2
                                    [category_id] => 9
                                    [parent_id] => 2
                                    [name] => Коляски
                                    [c_id] => 4
                                    [child] => Array
                                        (
                                            [7024] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [id] => 259
                                                    [file_id] => 2
                                                    [category_id] => 7024
                                                    [parent_id] => 9
                                                    [name] => Коляски-трости
                                                    [c_id] => 25
                                                    [child] => Array
                                                        (
                                                        )

                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )
)
```

убрались дубли и массив стал на один уровень меньше. ключ каждого блока массива это category_id.

Как тут быть? Сколько не пытаюсь, ничего не выходит.

Comment: А что вы этом массиве является дублями? array(... [id] => 244 [name] => Детский транспорт.....) по ним есть дубли, но у каждого разное содержание  [child] => Array.

Comment: @Ale_x , нужно объединить по ключам. Неправильно сформулировал, сори.
Т.е. если уже какой-то массив со своими child, то остальные объединить.

Comment: @Ale_x, невозможно там уже отвечать. 
Обновление не помогло. Так же "хавает" часть категорий.

Я вытаскиваю из БД определенные категории. Потом мне нужно из них собрать дерево включая всю их вложенность. Т.е. если выбрана подкатегория 3 уровня, то мне нужно выводить не только ее, но и уровни выше.

Этот массив, который в примере, я получаю в результате как-раз функции, которая формирует полную вложенность. Но она возвращает с повторами и т.д...

Вот мне и нужно уже пройтись по этому массиву, чтобы объединить дубли.

Comment: мда... Посмотри  описание структуры хранения дерева Nested Set- и забудешь про свой геморрой с выводом (мне в свое время помогло). Погугли, очень понадобится.

Comment: @Ale_x, это проект уже запущенный. Переделывать не вариант вообще.

Comment: обновил ответ)

Comment: да не за что)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

посмотри оно?

UPD

```
$narr=[];
foreach ($arr as $value)
{
    foreach ($value as $key => $val)
    {
        if (array_key_exists($key, $narr))
        {
              $narr[$key]= array_replace_recursive($narr[$key],$val);
        }
        else
        {    
            $narr[$key]=$val;
        }

    }

}
```

результат

```
array (
  2 => 
  array (
    'id' => 244,
    'file_id' => 2,
    'category_id' => 2,
    'parent_id' => 0,
    'name' => 'Детский транспорт',
    'c_id' => 19,
    'child' => 
    array (
      9 => 
      array (
        'id' => 258,
        'file_id' => 2,
        'category_id' => 9,
        'parent_id' => 2,
        'name' => 'Коляски',
        'c_id' => 4,
        'child' => 
        array (
          7024 => 
          array (
            'id' => 259,
            'file_id' => 2,
            'category_id' => 7024,
            'parent_id' => 9,
            'name' => 'Коляски-трости',
            'c_id' => 25,
            'child' => 
            array (
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
  5 => 
  array (
    'id' => 1,
    'file_id' => 2,
    'category_id' => 5,
    'parent_id' => 0,
    'name' => 'Каталог детских игрушек',
    'c_id' => 0,
    'child' => 
    array (
      6 => 
      array (
        'id' => 8,
        'file_id' => 2,
        'category_id' => 6,
        'parent_id' => 5,
        'name' => 'Развивающие игрушки',
        'c_id' => 0,
        'child' => 
        array (
          28 => 
          array (
            'id' => 20,
            'file_id' => 2,
            'category_id' => 28,
            'parent_id' => 6,
            'name' => 'Развивающие пособия',
            'c_id' => 0,
            'child' => 
            array (
              26 => 
              array (
                'id' => 21,
                'file_id' => 2,
                'category_id' => 26,
                'parent_id' => 28,
                'name' => 'Учим буквы, цифры и слова',
                'c_id' => 19,
                'child' => 
                array (
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
)
```

покажи что тут пропало? я что- то не вижу(

Comment: Для обработки да, результат такой нужен. Только тут часть массива пропала.
нету кучи веток.

Comment: всмысле пропали?

Comment: В прямом. Нет части массива. Например, пропал четвертый уровень (child) массива.

Comment: странно.


вот принт массива до обработки вашим кодом http://pastebin.com/1UKXPZGg

а вот после http://pastebin.com/rkwkHib5

видно, что части нет.

Comment: исправил) посмотри

Comment: ))

Теперь выводит повторы второго уровня, ибо $key не совпадает.

Т.е. у второго уровня ключи массива не совпадают с category_id.

Походу, там нужно пробегать по всем элементам массива.

Comment: посмотри щас. А вообще вопрос - откуда такие массивы? не из БД случаем?

Answer (score 0):

Как и с простым массивом - доступ по ключу массива, либо через foreach()